# AS3 - Clone an object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a game with a variety of ship types. My `Ship` class has a static array holding one of each of the types in it. Whenever I make a new `Ship` (other than when initializing this array), I want to make it a clone of one of the existing `Ship` objects in my prototype array.

1 - How can I run through all the properties in one `Ship` object and assign them to a second `Ship` object?

2 - How can I see if a property is an object or a basic type like `String` or `int`? Some of the objects in my `Ship` class need to be cloned, and some are just references that need to stay the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One option, arguably the most agile, would be to define clone methods for each class that you need to clone, such as:

```
class Ship
{
    public var prop1:Number;
    public var otherClassInstance:OtherClass;
    public function clone():Ship
    {
        var result:Ship = new Ship();
        result.prop1 = this.prop1;
        result.otherClassInstance = this.otherClassInstance.clone()
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public var prop1:Number;
    public function clone():OtherClass
    {
        var result:OtherClass = new OtherClass();
        result.prop1 = this.prop1;
    }
}
```

Another option is to clone an object by using the ByteArray class like this example from the Adobe documentation:

```
function clone( source:Object ):* 
{ 
    var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    myBA.writeObject( source ); 
    myBA.position = 0; 
    return( myBA.readObject() ); 
}
```

I've seen instances where this approach does not work for cloning instances of custom classes, specifically view classes like Sprites.

Another approach is to use `describeType` from the `flash.utils` package. With `describeType` you can iterate through the properties of an object.

Here is an example of using `describeType` to inspect the properties of an object that is a part of a [utils lib](https://github.com/makemachine/makemachine.actionscript/blob/master/src/makemachine/utils/introspect.as) I wrote.

As for checking the type of the property, you can use `describeType` or you can also use the `is` operator like this:

```
if( myObj is SomeClass )
{

}

if( myObj is OtherClass )
{

}
```

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do your first suggestion, though this has the problem of if I add new variables to my classes, I will have to add new lines to clone() every time.

Comment: That has advantages too. Perhaps you might want to set a default value if no value is set or you may want to clone some props and not others. An automated approach using describeType would not be too flexible.

Answer (score 4):

To run through all the properties of one ship object and assign them to a second:

```
shipobj1:Ship = new Ship();
//set values for all shipobj1 properties

shipobj2:Ship = new Ship();

for (item in shipobj2)
    item = shipobj1[item];
```

Checking if a property value is an object you could use typeof.  The limitation of this is that there are only 6 possible types returned:  boolean, function, number, object, string, and xml.  So for example if you need to know if a property is an array you can't really do that with typeof since that would actually return "object" since "array" isn't one of the 6 options, but if you're just concerned with identifying simple types like numbers and strings versus other stuff it should do the trick:

```
if(typeof item == "object")
  // do whatever with object
else if(typeof item == "string")
  // do whatever with string
//etc, etc.
```

EDIT: Replaced variable "var" with "item" since var is a reserved word.

Comment: You can use the is keyword for stricter matching. e.g. if(something is Array)

Comment: I get a number of syntax errors with `for (var in shipobj2)
    var = shipobj1[var];`

Comment: That could be because "var" is a reserved word or because you call it obj2 in for statement and obj1 within the loop.

Comment: My bad using "var" in the example code as a variable name - replaced it with "item".